# Does the Twitter Bootstrap 3 conflict with D3.js/Dimple.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a cluster bar chart that will display individual bar hover labels fine without the Twitter Bootstrap 3. As soon as I add it into my file, the hover label's content goes blank.

Here's my file: http://pastebin.com/CHkftwcZ

If you remove lines 11 and 42, the labels will appear properly with the content reflecting the values of the individual bars in the chart.

Tested in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it happen to be so.
CSS class `tooltip` is used both by Bootstrap and Dimple.js.
They don't much interfere though, except for the `opacity` property.

To fix it add something like this to your stylesheet:

```
svg .tooltip { opacity: 1; }
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3UFsB/1/) based on the pastebin that you provided.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tip... wondering how I would have even figured this out.